# Set transparent when mouse hover in datagrid row in WINUI3/UWP?

Tags: .net, windows, xaml, winui-3

I'm trying to set transparent when the mouse hovers in the data grid in winui3 using the community toolkit. My code is below here...

public DataGridControl()
{
this.SelectionChanged += DataGridControl_SelectionChanged;
this.PointerEntered += DataGridControl_PointerEntered;

```
    }

    private void DataGridControl_PointerEntered(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (sender is not DataGrid dataGrid)
        {
            return;
        }

        // DataGridRow has an "IsSelected" property but it's internal.
        // We can use Reflection to get this property.
        Type dataGridRowType = typeof(DataGridRow);
        PropertyInfo? isSelectedProperty = dataGridRowType.GetProperty("IsSelected", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        foreach (DataGridRow dataGridRow in dataGrid.FindDescendants().OfType<DataGridRow>())
        {
            if (isSelectedProperty?.GetValue(dataGridRow) is bool isSelected &&
                isSelected is true)
            {
                dataGridRow.Background = DataGridRowSelectedBackgroundBrush;
                continue;
            }

            dataGridRow.Background = dataGrid.Background;
        }
    }
    private SolidColorBrush DataGridRowSelectedBackgroundBrush { get; set; } = new(Colors.Transparent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
dataGridRow.Background = dataGrid.Background;
```

The code above won't work. The `DataGridRow` has an inner `Rectangle` for its `Background`.
(See line 659 in [DataGrid.xaml](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/main/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGrid.xaml).)

Overriding the `DataGridRowSelectedHoveredBackgroundColor` should work:

```xml
<toolkit:DataGrid>
    <toolkit:DataGrid.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedHoveredBackgroundColor">Transparent</Color>
    </toolkit:DataGrid.Resources>
</toolkit:DataGrid>
```